# Nativescript 1.7 : white screen after app launched

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

Since I upgraded to nativescript 1.7, I have a little issue once I launch my app. Indeed I get a white screen after I type "tns livesync android" or "tns run android". There's probably an error but I have no message.

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide more details. What is your project setup. What Angular version. How is Android and NativeScript related to Angular and Android in your project?

Comment: Thank you for answering 
As for your question, I'm developing a mobile application with Nativescript & Angular 2 (if you use Angular with Nativescrit, you can only use the version 2). For the details, well when I launch the application, a login page is supposed to be displayed on the screen but instead of that I only get a white screen with no error message. And I only got this issue since I upgraded to Nativescript 1.7

Comment: I don't understand why someone would give you a negative mark for your question...that is a good question and with enough details. Everyone who works with NativeScript and Angular knows that will be Angular2.

Comment: @LeoCaseiro I guess I shouldn't have out the "android" tag. Because of that, all of the Android developers saw the question but since some of them are not familiar with Nativescript (I guess), they're not able to help me. Anyway Nativescript and Angular 2 have been updated since so my question is irrelevant now

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issue. Unfortunately, there are lots of issues with the android side after the update to v1.7.0. The Nativescript team should be releasing a patch today (21/03/16) to fix the issues, so hold tight.